Error (WebView, Expo Intent (open payment method: KakaoPay, NaverPay)
does anyone know how to use React navite Webview and expo intent-launcher to open an app (kakaopay, naver pay, payco...?).
I have no idea why this doesn't work (it works on iOS with just Linking.openURL(url)), but on android nothing works yet
Here my basic config: ("react-native": "0.74.3", "expo": "~51.0.22")
import * as IntentLauncher from "expo-intent-launcher";

const payUrl = "https://......."
pay
const onShouldStartLoadWithRequest = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event);
    const url = event.url || "";

    if (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://") || url.startsWith("about:blank")) {
      return true;
    }
    console.log("url", url);
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      try {
        IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", {
          data: url,
        })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Payment gateway opened successfully");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Failed to open payment gateway:", error);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error launching intent:", error);
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      Linking.openURL(url).catch((err) => {
        console.log({ err });
        Alert.alert(
          "App execution failed. If it is not installed, please press the install button."
        );
      });
      return false;
    }
  };

return (
    <View className="flex-1">
      <WebView
        ref={handleSetRef}
        useWebKit={false}
        scalesPageToFit={Platform.OS !== "ios"}
        originWhitelist={["*"]}
        source={{ uri: payU`your text`rl }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        onLoad={NativeToWeb}
        onError={errorHandler}
        onMessage={WebToNative}
        onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
        setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
        javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically={true}
      />
    </View>
  );

I tried with the react-native-send-intent library
library, but as it's not compatible with expo, I thought I'd try theirs (Expo IntentLauncher).
On iOS I have no problem, but when I launch with my android (device) after building an .apk, I get an error.
So I added packagaes in my AndroidManifest.xml for example:
<package android:name=“com.kakao.talk” /> 
<package android:name=“com.samsung.android.spay” /> 

But nothing works

Add this:
if (Platform.OS === "android") {
  if (url.startsWith("intent:")) {
    const intents = url.split("#Intent;");
    const path = intents[0] || "";
    const query = intents[1] || "";
    const params = {};
    query.split(";").map((each) => {
      if (each.includes("=")) {
        const pairs = each.split("=");
        params[pairs[0]] = pairs[1];
      }
    });
    const scheme = params?.scheme;
    const packageName = params?.package;
    const data = path.replace("intent://", `${scheme}://`);
    try {
      IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", {
        data: data,
      })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Payment gateway opened successfully");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Failed to open payment gateway:", error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error launching intent in if condition", error);
    }
  } 


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
